# What precaution should users take when installing proprietary snaps to avoid malware?

Tags: snap, malware

Proprietary snaps contributed by a particular entity were removed from the snap store as described in [How to ask to ban the application for security reasons?](https://github.com/canonical-websites/snapcraft.io/issues/651).

What cautions should users take before installing proprietary snaps?

Comment: Only download from trusted sources and depending on your level of concern test it in a VM or other sandbox.

Comment: (Even though for debs, much of that is applicable to snaps or, for that matter, *any* packaging format.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to give you the same exact suggestions we (the community) would give for "random PPAs":

**Only use trusted sources for Snaps** (rather than 'random suggestions') **and if you really are concerned, test in an isolated VM or other isolated system/sandbox before putting it on a production machine to see if the snap does anything 'malicious'.**

Beyond this step, there's no real way to properly 'vet' Snaps on the catalog for 'maliciousness'.  If you find such a snap, though, you should report it to Canonical for immediate removal, and they can be pretty swift with that.  (The same goes for PPAs, within 24 hours they can erase such a malicious PPA).